# Ant: set property in 1 file, read it in another?

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

I have the following Ant buildfile `importer.xml`:

```
<project name="importer" basedir=".." default="build">
    <import file="imported.xml"/>

    <target name="build">
        <!-- Do some stuff... -->

        <property name="isRunningFromImporter" value="true"/>
        <antcall target="run-now"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

And another buildfile `imported.xml` that uses the ant-contrib tasks:

```
<project name="importer" basedir=".." default="build">
    <!-- Most of file omitted for brevity -->

    <target name="run-now">
        <if>
            <not-equals arg1="${isRunningFromImporter}" arg2="true"/>
            <then>
                <!--
                    This should only execute when the
                    isRunningFromImporter property is not true.
                -->
            </then>
        </if>
    </target>
</project>
```

The `imported#run-now` target can be ran as a standalone Ant task, for example:

> ant -buildfile imported.xml run-now

In this case I do not want the `<then>` clause/task executed. However, if you run the same task as it is imported into `importer.xml`:

> ant -buildfile importer.xml build

Then I want the `<then>` clause/task to execute, however, Ant does no allow me to see a property in one file and read it in another. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does what you want by default.  Antcall's "inheritAll" attribute is set to true.

Running the following code echo's "true" showing the property is in fact set.

```
<project name="importer" basedir=".." default="build">
    <import file="imported.xml"/>

    <target name="build">
        <!-- Do some stuff... -->

        <property name="isRunningFromImporter" value="true"/>
        <antcall target="run-now"/>
    </target>
</project>

<project name="importer" basedir="..">
    <!-- Most of file omitted for brevity -->

    <target name="run-now">

        <echo>${isRunningFromImporter}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

I'm not familiar with `<not-equals arg1="${isRunningFromImporter}" arg2="true"/>`.  I've always used `<not><equals ...>` instead.  Where does not-equals come from?  Are you sure the problem isn't in that line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following idiom to determine automatically whether a particular build file is the main file called by the user or whether it has been imported:

```
<project name="projectA">
  <!-- set a property if this file is standalone, don't set it if imported -->
  <condition property="projectA.standalone">
    <equals arg1="${ant.file}" arg2="${ant.file.projectA}" />
  </condition>

  <target name="standalone-only" if="projectA.standalone">
    <echo>I am standalone</echo>
  </target>

  <target name="imported-only" unless="projectA.standalone">
    <echo>I have been imported</echo>
  </target>
</project>
```

The trick here is that the implicit property `ant.file` is set to the path of the *main* build file that was specified on the command line (or used implicitly if it's called `build.xml`), but in addition Ant sets properties `ant.file.PROJECTNAME` to the path of the relevant build file for every (main or imported) `<project name="PROJECTNAME">`.  Thus `${ant.file} == ${ant.file.PROJECTNAME}` if and only if `PROJECTNAME` is the top-level build file.